# Entity Framework - Only updates the first char of the data table columns fields

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I've just recently been using the EF just because I thought it was simplier and faster to have a DAL that way...but it's a pain in the ....s

After solving severam problems I can't sucessfully updade dada from my tables in a sql database.

I have a aspx form that edits some fieds in the entity object (System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject) and then I call the EntitiesContext.SaveChanges()...and it actually saves changes. But in the WRONG way.

For instance if the forma has this data:
Name:abcd
Number:1234

the saved data will be 
Name:a
Number:1

Please don't send me begginers documentation I've seen it all!
And yes... I have the Store procedures created and I've recreated the .edmx several times!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that your stored procedures are bringing in parameters that are only 1 character long? I don't do any EF work, but I have had problems in the past where I will accidentally declare parameters in my stored procedures wrong and it will only work with as much data as could fit in the wrongly-declared params.

Comment: Ok. I had a feeling it wasn't but I don't think it hurts to cover all possible bases.

Comment: I'm so ashamed. You'r right....!!!
I had @FName  as VarChar because I thought they would put some default 256 or somthing...like in sql 2000!

Thank you!